# Maximal ideals in $\mathbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\mathbb Z[i]=\{a+bi \mid a,b∈ℤ\}$ be a subring of $ℂ$. 
Consider two principal ideals $I=(7)$ and $J=(13)$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$. Is the ideal $I$ maximal? Is the ideal $J$ maximal?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:

A principal ideal $(a)$ in a PID $R$ is maximal iff $a$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 5):

HINT for second question:
$$ 13 = (3 + 2i)(3 - 2i) $$